# JSON-RPC Error - Exection Reverted (-32000) / Empty ABI

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, compilation, bsc

I am attempting to deploy a BEP20 contract on BSC testnet via Remix. I am using compiler v6.12 and am successfully compiling my Solidity. However, when I deploy the contract, I am receiving the following error:

`Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }`

My gas limit is set to *3000000* and this is my log output:`

```
 status false Transaction mined but execution failed
 transaction hash   0x447...e5e5c
 from   0x4698a3...1e0f94F
 to TestContract.(constructor)
 gas    3000000 gas
 transaction cost   653237 gas
 hash   0x44745d2c2e321...9e5e5c
 input  0x60c...c0033
 decoded input  {}
 decoded output  -
 logs   []
 value  0 wei
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This took me few hours pulling my hairs, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed!**

The issue was that I used the mainnet PancakeSwapV2 router address, and not the testnet one. For anyone else encountering this issue, the mainnet router is:

```
0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
```

and the testnet one is:

```
0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: What do you mean with router address? Where have you changed that? I'm getting this same error sending an erc20 transaction to metamask which is connected to ropsten :S